# How to display cross mark in images on touch event?

Tags: android, image, ontouchlistener

In my project there is an image. When the user touches any place in the image, it should be marked with a cross sign. Also we have to clear this cross on a button click. I managed to display the image. What do I have to do in the `ontouchlistener()` function to display the  cross point? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

I would create a custom `ImageView`, something like:

```
public class MarkableImageView extends ImageView {

    ArrayList<Marker> mMarkers;

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        for(Marker m : mMarkers) {
            // draw the marker
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mMarkers.add(new Marker(e.getX(), e.getY()));
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void reset() {
        mMarkers.clear();
        invalidate();
    }

    // this class will be visible only inside MarkableImageView
    private class Marker {
        public int x;
        public int y;
        // you might want to add other properties, for example
        // if you need to have different types of markers

        public Marker(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @neoHacker: it's an inner class that you might want to create to represent a marker.

Comment: sorry , I don' understand. I'm new bee. can you make it simple. Pls

Comment: @neoHacker: I added a Marker class, see above. You also might want to read [Building Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

Comment: bro can you give the same sample project in the github

Answer (score 1):

This code is working 100 %. If you have still any questions then you can contact me.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
{   
    if (event.getAction() == 1) 
    {                
            GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                (int) event.getX(),
                (int) event.getY());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "lat and longtd is \n "+
                    p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + 
                    p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 , 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //
               mapView.getOverlays().add(new MarkerOverlay(p));
                mapView.invalidate();
    } 

    return true;
}
```

and also define another(2nd) overlay class... where this event will get.

```
class MarkerOverlay extends Overlay
{
    private GeoPoint p;
    private Projection projection; 

    public MarkerOverlay(GeoPoint p)
    {
        this.p = p;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,boolean shadow, long when)
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        //---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.pir_pictr);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);

        return true;   
     }



 }
```

Comment: I think he is not talking about any map in the question. Just about image.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking for a solution to this. I need to make round mark on an image where user touches. I'm also going to remote control a device with this infomation. What i found as a solution i'll provide next. What I'm facing as a problem is as the dpi and device screens changes this marking operation needs calibration. I'm trying to improve the method. But also maybe it is useful for someone.

Here it is:

1) Method: First create image with a program like Gimp or photoshop (or ...) . In the layout, place an imageview. Put the image to that imageview with the original size. (this is the weak point #1). For the onTouchEvent add the following code. What code will do is create 2 drawables. Create 2 layers. 1st layer is the image(above) and second layer is the mark. Then place the mark where user touches. (this is the weak point #2).

2) Code:

```
// On the top
public ImageView ptable;
Drawable[] layers;
```

Then

```
//OnCreateView
ptable = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_ptable);
layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.pratik);
layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.pratik);
LayerDrawable ldr = new LayerDrawable(layers);
ptable.setImageDrawable(ldr);
```

Then

```
ptable.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            String text = "Click X:"+ String.valueOf(event.getX())+ " Y:" + String.valueOf(event.getY());


            //Dokunulan yere bir işaret oluştur.
            Bitmap mark = Bitmap.createBitmap(600, 400,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas ca = new Canvas(mark);
            Paint pa = new Paint();
            pa.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            pa.setAntiAlias(true);
            //pa.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            pa.setStrokeWidth((float)3);
            pa.setARGB(251, 20, 20, 20);
            float cx = event.getX() + 10 + (8*event.getX()/100);
            float cy = event.getY() + 10 + (6*event.getY()/100);

            ca.drawCircle(cx, cy, 13, pa);
            BitmapDrawable bmp = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), mark);
            layers[1] = (Drawable)bmp;
            LayerDrawable ldr = new LayerDrawable(layers);
            ptable.setImageDrawable(ldr);



            return true;
        }

    });
```

This code is working but working correct only with a certain screen size and pixel density.
I'm going to improve this.

Comment: Ok. I finalized the solution. if i match the bitmaps sizes (600,400) to the imageView.getMeasuredWidth() and .getMeasuredHeight() it works like a charm. I changed the res, gravity, fill ... with all it works fine.

Comment: your code is working, thanks a lot.can you tell me how to add image like as a pin image and lock the pin in the image part.I also want to create a popup when I click on the pin image. Is it possible.If you have sample code please provide me.

Comment: For this i don't have a sample code but i can suggest to draw pin image into layer 1 drawable instead drawing the circle. For popup, you can hook onlongpress event and show your dialog.

Comment: Bro please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014212/how-to-place-pin-mark-image-over-an-image-using-ontouchlistener I am expect your honourable reply.god bless

Comment: bro I try to change layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.pratik) to layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.mypinImg) the layer is overlapped.

Comment: Ok. I have checked your question. You want to place markers and then you want them stay there. Also at a later time you also want to click on them. With my method it will be a little bit hard. Because the image has only 2 layers. With every pin add operation you need to draw all pins to layer[1] again and again. Since this is a canvas you can only get coordinates on clicks. Also pins will overlap. You can create a table to match the clicks and the coordinates.

Comment: The first setting of layer [1] is done with same images to draw an empty layout just with the base image. Then on every touch the mark is drawn on a canvas which is as the same size with the base image. Drawcircle does that. In your case you can use drawBitmap.

Comment: friend can you give any Github sample project.

Comment: Unfortunately now i cannot. Because i've written this code by myself. But if i happen to see some i will write here.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 images with two ImageView
- One without cross mark say no_cross.png - image_view1.
- Another is with cross mark say with_cross.png - image_view2.

Place them at same position in xml. Initially visibility of image_view2 (containig with_cross.png) is invisible.

```
android:visibilty="gone"
```

OnImage touch make visibility of with_cross.png to visible and no_cross.png to invisible.

`setVisibility(View.GONE)` for image_view1
`setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` for image_view2

On Button touch do reverse.

`setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` for image_view1
`setVisibility(View.GONE)` for image_view2

Comment: But i don't have any idea where the target mark is to be placed until user touches there.