# How to mark a spot over an image in android?

Tags: android, image, touch

I would like to know how to mark a spot over an image.Marking would be on the touch of the screen would have an image to show that touch has been made over there.How can I achieve this, any example would be helpful.Thanks

Comment: I have tried the basic Draw method only,but its of no use.

Comment: Look here. You can find answer of similar type of question

[How to diaplay cross mark in images on touch event?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612106/how-to-diaplay-cross-mark-in-images-on-touch-event

Comment: have you tried looking at the OnTouchListener event?

Comment: @Karthik have you got the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

In Activity override onTouchEvent method from which you can get the Event and from which you can get the complete information about the Touch (i.e., X, Y Cordinates, Pressure that user kept on the screen and even multiple Touch and many more).

Take the ImageView and override onDraw and draw the desired image at (X,Y) coordinates. Just use a small Loop to make it invisible continuously which looks like a haptic feedback.

Use the below code to make it transparent

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
myImage.setAlpha(127);
```

Thats it. You will get the desired effect if you properly worked on the above code.