# How to place pin mark image over an image in android?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, drawable

I am new to Android. I am developing a project where I will get the Radio signal values(I can get the values from API). I have a floor plan.  The floor plan has kitchen,hall,bedroom sections.. If I click the Kitchen section, I need to place an Pin Image in that section with Radio signal values. Once I click Save, I need to lock the Image(with values) in that particular section. Similarly I can place many Pin images based on the requirement.

Please give me some related link or sample codes to develop this. I have attached the Image for your reference. Any help would be really appreciated.

[image]

Comment: After getting values from API, with respect to particular data set boolean values with it in "isPinned" so that you can know that when to show pop up.
For displaying pin on view, good idea will be that create layout such that textview and pin overlay so that you just need to manage show and hide pin image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use canvas.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map);
    canvas.drawBitmap(map, xPositionForMap, yPositionForMap, null);

    Bitmap marker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.marker);
    canvas.drawBitmap(marker, xPositionFor1stMarker, yPositionFor1stMarker, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(marker, xPositionFor2ndMarker, yPositionFor2ndMarker, null);
}
```

Things drawn later in the onDraw appear on top of those drawn earlier. Probably the BitmapFactory.decodeResource should be in a create/init mat hod so they aren't called every time onDraw is called. See http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html for more information.

For clicking on the pins you would catch clicks on the Layout containing the canvas and conditionally add extra drawables and text.

An alternative way is to use RelativeLayout and put ImageView, which would work similarly.

Comment: bro can you send any example application source code from github or anything?

Comment: Here is a project from Romain Guy that demonstrates the kind of application structure you would have. It is quite complicated but might get you started. This file shows a View with an onDraw method: https://github.com/romainguy/road-trip/blob/master/application/src/main/java/org/curiouscreature/android/roadtrip/StateView.java

Comment: Thanks a lot I try then I inform you bro.god bless

Comment: Bro I successfully add the dynamic pin imageView on RelativeLayout.Now I want to save the Layout with ImageView.Is it possible? Which one is best shared preference or store sqlite. I want to store all Layout(Images) like a gallery.When I click a Layout(image) from my gallery the Image is open with pin images.I troubled in this concept Please help me bro..

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on this library, may be this will help you [ImageLayout](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/ImageLayout)

Comment: Thanks for your reply friend,Are you have any idea to store the layout? Please help me to store the layout with pin mark images.