# How to get onTouch x and y value in setOnLongClickListener?

Tags: android

Run Time I have change the background image(set background). In the image, I have perform the action using Touch Listener. But in my case, I need another action on Touch event. For that purpose I need to proceed with long touch event. Suggest me, any other idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324362/detect-touch-press-vs-long-press-vs-movement

Comment: @ScionofIkshvaku How to get Motion event value in imageButton.setOnLongClickListener ?

Comment: you can get the values using `ev.getX()` or `ev.getX()` on `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`

Comment: Cant able to get MotionEvent in imageButton.setOnLongClickListener.

Comment: not in long click use `onTouchEvent` method in `TouchLIstener`

Comment: I need solution for long click, could you please guide me if any possible way.

Comment: u need x, y values when long click is performed? right?

Comment: Yes .i need x and y values on long click.

Comment: then update your question accordingly

Comment: Still Am searching the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Answering from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11679788/1576416):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
        Log.i("", "Long press!");
        if(myEvent!=null)
        {
           int requiredXvalue=myEvent.getX();               
           int requiredYvalue=myEvent.getY();

        }
    }   
};
MotionEvent myEvent;
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView){
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 1000);
        myEvent=event;
    }
    if((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)||(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP))
        handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event, mapView);
}
```

**OR**

you can use Gesture Detector as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7921439/1576416):

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e("", "Longpress detected");
        int requiredXvalue=e.getX();               
        int requiredYvalue=e.getY();
    }
});

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
};
```

Comment: this.event=event; which detail I have to assign here.

Comment: Am using imageView on relative Layout. Which detail I have to provide instead of MapView.

Comment: provide ImageView object

Comment: 'Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, ImageView btn) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 1000);
            myevent=event;
        }
        if((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)||(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP))
            handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
        return onTouchEvent(event,btn);
    }'
Shows the error in @Override

Comment: you need to set a `TouchListener` for your image view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014212/how-to-place-pin-mark-image-over-an-image-in-android am searching result for that. here am loading 1st image in relative layout(setting as background image)

Comment: Next step Overlay another imageView(Mark) during the onTouch. In my case, I need onTouch to perform Zoom and longTouch to place the imageView. After placing the imageView, Performing the action.

Comment: I have tried your code. Both actions performed in onTouch itself.

Comment: can I able to set onLongPress for particular layout(Relative Layout) in a Activity

Answer (score 0):

```
         imageButton.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 

                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I believe in this case `onLongClick` should actually return `true`, as the touch event should be consumed

Comment: Unable to get the Motion event in setOnLongClickListener.